# Rewrite mods with two GET variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change url from mydomain.com/search.php?page=1&postcode=xxx

to: mydomain.com/search/1/xxx

I know how to change url from mydomain.com/search.php?page=1 to mydomain.com/search/1
This can be done with this:

```
RewriteRule    ^search/([0-9]+)/?$    search.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

How can I add another GET to my url?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ search.php?page=$1&postcode=$2 [NC,L]
```